# Is there something wrong with my gets function? we haven't been though about fgets yet in class. only gets

Tags: c

for example when I type in a string "Hello", when I press 'a' it should print "There are 2 vowels." Instead, it says there are 0. I'm new to programming and this is the first language I am learning. Help?

```
    /*
        Student: Josiah Eleazar T. Regencia
        Course: BSIT 1
        Subject: SCS 101
        Professor: Daniel B. Garcia


        Problem definition:
            Write a menu program that will count the vowels and consonants in the string

*/

#include <stdio.h> //printf and scanf functions
#include <string.h> //string functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define PROMPT "Type in a word, a phrase, or a sentence." //instucts the user

/*
    Declaring the function for the user's menu
*/
void menu();

/*
    Declaration of function needed to count the vowels in the string
*/
int vowel_count(char *stringInput); //declaring the function to count the vowels sounds

/*
    Declaration of function needed to count the consonants in the stringn
*/
int consonant_count(char *stringInput); //declaring the functions to count the consonant sounds

/*
    Declaring the function needed to convert the streeting to uppercase
*/
int uppercase(char *stringInput);

/*
    Declaring the function needed to convert the streeting to uppercase
*/
int lowercase(char *stringInput);

int main () {


    char userInput[100]; // the string the user inputs

    char commandKey[1]; //this key is for the menu

    char newInput[100]; //this is for the new input to user will put in

    int stringLength; //to identify the length of the string

    /*
        Variables for counting the vowels and consonants
    */

    int consonantCount;

    printf("%s\n\n", PROMPT); //instucts the user

    gets(userInput);

    stringLength = strlen(userInput); //gets the length of the string

    //fgets(userInput, 100, stdin);

    /*if(stringLength > 0 && userInput[stringLength - 1] == '\n') {

        userInput[stringLength - 1] ='\0';
    }*/

    menu(); //prints out the menu for the user to pick his options

    /*
        The loop will run what the user asks the program to run while at the same time also asking
        what the programmer wants next
    */
    while(*commandKey != 'X' || *commandKey != 'x') {

        //int commandLength; //length of the command key

        printf("Enter your menu selection: ");

        gets(commandKey);

        /*commandLength = strlen(commandKey);

        fgets(commandKey, 100, stdin);

        if(commandLength > 0 && commandKey[commandLength - 1] == '\n') {

        commandKey[commandLength - 1] ='\0';
    }*/

        if(*commandKey == 'A' || *commandKey == 'a') {

            int vowelCount;

            vowelCount = vowel_count(userInput);

            printf("There are %d vowels.\n\n", vowelCount);

        }

        if(*commandKey == 'B' || *commandKey == 'b') {

            consonantCount = consonant_count(userInput);

            printf("There are %d consonants.\n\n", consonantCount);
        }

        if(*commandKey == 'C' || *commandKey == 'c') {

            /*
                This condition simply converts the input string to all lowercase letters
            */

            lowercase(userInput);
        }

        if(*commandKey == 'D' || *commandKey == 'd') {

            /*
                This condition simply converts the input string to all lowercase letters
            */

            uppercase(userInput);
        }

        if(*commandKey == 'E' || *commandKey == 'e') {

            /*
                Prints the current string
                if the string was converted in lowercase letters, the outcome would be all lowercase letters
                if the string was converted in uppercase letters, the outcome would be all uppercase letters
            */

            printf("%s\n\n", userInput);
        }

        if(*commandKey == 'F' || *commandKey == 'f') {

            /*
                When the user wants to test a new string, this is the condition for the user
                to automatically ask of it
            */

            printf("%s\n", PROMPT);
            gets(newInput);
            strcpy(userInput, newInput);
        }

        if(*commandKey == 'M' || *commandKey =='m') {

            /*
                In case the user forgets, this will serve as a reminder of the menu
            */

            menu();
        }

        if(*commandKey == 'X' || *commandKey == 'x') {
            printf("Goodbye!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Function that displays the menu.
void menu() {

    /*
        These are the set of command keys given to the user
    */
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("PRESS:\n\n");
    printf("         A - Count the number of vowels in the string.\n");
    printf("         B - Count the number of consonants in the string.\n");
    printf("         C - Convert the string to uppercase.\n");
    printf("         D - Convert the string to lowecase.\n");
    printf("         E - Display the current string.\n");
    printf("         F - Enter another string.\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("         M - Display this menu.\n");
    printf("         X - Exit the program.\n");
    printf("\n\n");
}

/*
    Defining the function for the vowel counting
*/

int vowel_count(char *stringInput) {

    if ( *stringInput == '\0')
        return 0;
    else
        return vowel_count(stringInput + 1) + (*stringInput == 'a' || *stringInput == 'A')
                                            + (*stringInput == 'e' || *stringInput == 'E')
                                            + (*stringInput == 'i' || *stringInput == 'I')
                                            + (*stringInput == 'o' || *stringInput == 'O')
                                            + (*stringInput == 'u' || *stringInput == 'U');
}

/*
    Defining the function for the vowel counting
*/
int consonant_count(char *stringInput) {

    if (*stringInput == '\0')
        return 0;
    else
        return consonant_count(stringInput + 1) + (*stringInput == 'b' || *stringInput == 'B')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'c' || *stringInput == 'C')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'd' || *stringInput == 'D')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'f' || *stringInput == 'F')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'g' || *stringInput == 'G')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'h' || *stringInput == 'H')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'j' || *stringInput == 'J')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'k' || *stringInput == 'K')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'l' || *stringInput == 'L')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'm' || *stringInput == 'M')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'n' || *stringInput == 'N')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'p' || *stringInput == 'P')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'q' || *stringInput == 'Q')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'r' || *stringInput == 'R')
                                                + (*stringInput == 's' || *stringInput == 'S')
                                                + (*stringInput == 't' || *stringInput == 'T')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'v' || *stringInput == 'V')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'w' || *stringInput == 'W')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'x' || *stringInput == 'X')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'y' || *stringInput == 'Y')
                                                + (*stringInput == 'z' || *stringInput == 'Z');
}

/*
    Defining the function for the conversion of the string to all uppercase letters
*/
int uppercase(char *stringInput) {

    while(*stringInput) {

        *stringInput = toupper(*stringInput);

        stringInput++;
    }

}

/*
    Defining the function for the conversion of the string to all uppercase letters
*/
int lowercase(char *stringInput) {

    while(*stringInput) {

        *stringInput = tolower(*stringInput);

        stringInput++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tell "Daniel B. Garcia" to stop using `gets`. It has been removed from the language.

Comment: To see if your `gets()` call is working, try adding a `printf("you typed in: %s\n", userInput);` line after your `gets()` call. If it prints out what you expect, then you know your problem is elsewhere. This is called debugging.

Comment: Okay. But, what should I do with this code? How can I make it work? I've been working on this for hours all ready. :/

Comment: Use your (currently commented) `fgets` call instead of `gets`, but use `sizeof userInput` instead of hard-coding `100`. That way you don't have to update the `fgets`-call if you decide to change the size of `userInput`.

Comment: This: `while(*commandKey != 'X' || *commandKey != 'x')` is a problem (but probably not the problem you're asking about) because the condition will always be true.

Comment: Tanks a lot for the advice Mr. @MichaelBurr.

Comment: You should ignore the pedants here because your problems have nothing to do with gets.

Comment: @JimBalter: You're probably right that the problem isn't related to `gets` -- but he certainly should be aware that `gets` is dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop will never stop:

```
while(*commandKey != 'X' || *commandKey != 'x')
```

A loop stops when its condition is false. For `*commandKey != 'X' || *commandKey != 'x'` to be false, it is logically equivalent for `*commandKey == 'X' && *commandKey == 'x'` to be true, which doesn't quite work. `*commandKey` can't be both `'X'` and `'x'`.

Instead, you want:

```
while(*commandKey != 'X' && *commandKey != 'x')
```

Which will stop when `*commandKey` is `'X'` or `'x'`.

Also, you never initialized `commandKey`, so you can't test it in the loop (using values of uninitialized variables is undefined behavior). And if you want to treat it as a string, you need to declare it such that it holds at least 2 characters, because the null character is needed:

`char commandKey[2] = { 0 };`

This will initialize `commandKey` to an empty string. Remember that `gets()` will null-terminate the string, so, even if your command is just one key, `gets()` will need at least 2 positions to fill - the character command and the null terminating byte. Alternatively, you can leave `commandKey` as is (provided that you initialize it), and use `getchar()` instead, which reads one single character.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! My program is now correct. This was exactly what I needed to correct.

Comment: @user3385560: The way to indicate that is to accept the answer by clicking the checkbox next to it.

Comment: oops. haha. My bad. New guy here. Thanks for the info :D